# When generating a view from a model using MVC/EF in Visual studio it's empty

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

When I go to create a new view, I reference for example my Contact model shown below and choose either list or create or whatever.

Every time, regardless of the action and model I choose the form is empty other than the basic framework.

```
 public class Contact
{
    String Name { get; set; }
    String Phone { get; set; }
    String PhoneCellCarrier { get; set; }
    String AltPhone { get; set; }
    String AltPhoneCellCarrier { get; set; }
    String Email { get; set; }
    Boolean EmailAlert { get; set; }
    Boolean TextAlert { get; set; }
}
```

For example the View that is generated when I choose a Create template for the model above is this.

```
@model Project.Models.Contact


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Contact</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger"     })
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn     btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: What were you expecting to see there ?

Comment: The generic form that EF builds given a model. It will create a text box for example for a string in the model.

Comment: @Preston How should mvc be supposed to know if you want a form or not? How the page should look like etc?

Comment: @AlexanderDerck I don't understand the question since this is a pretty standard feature of MVC. You create the models and then it will automagically generate basic controllers and views using templates based on them. Anyway my issue was resolved by marking all the objects in the model as public.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objects in the Model need the public access modifier in order for the HTML template to be generated.